# Where and how does one verify compatible replacement parts?

Tags: replace, repair

Going to the salvage yard tomorrow, looking for an [engine oil pan](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/oil-pan-threads-stripped).

After some research, it appears oil pans from other model Fords ***may*** be comparable but I do not see any information that verifies it.

Where and how does one verify compatible replacement parts?

Comment: What is the model of Ford you have?

Comment: See my comment on your other question. If all your oil changes were done by the dealership, you should make them replace it for free, since the only way it could be stripped is if they stripped it by improperly reinstalling the plug bolt (probably cross-threading it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The salvage yard will use an interchange manual. At one time it was a large series of books but is now a computer program. Each major and some not so major component of a vehicle was given a number. The number is then cataloged and all vehicles that use the same part are listed. When I have doubts I'll check several on line sources of parts. If one source says a 96 Taurus and a 97 Sable part interchange I look up the part for each at several vendors. If each source lists matching part numbers I assume they are the same. There can be confusion as sometimes manufacturers will modify a part mid model year so they will interchange allowing them reduce inventory. This means that an early 1996 part may not fit but a late 1996 part will. I would bring the part and make sure they look the same.